# Can I use a .sql file in my Magento module installer?

Tags: module, database, magento-1, sql, setup-script

I have a large SQL file. Can I use this in my module installer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, if you follow the naming conventions for install scripts. For example:

```
app/code/local/Your/Module/sql/your_module_setup/install-1.0.0.sql
app/code/local/Your/Module/sql/your_module_setup/upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.sql
```

<del>Or as data install script (if you are not adding/changing tables):</del>

<del>app/code/local/Your/Module/data/your_module_setup/data-install-1.0.0.sql
    app/code/local/Your/Module/data/your_module_setup/data-upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.sql</del>

*Update: for data install scripts, the SQL extension is not working.*

You need to define the setup resource `your_module_setup` and the current version number in the module's **config.xml** like this:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_Module>
             <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Your_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <your_module_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Your_Module</module>
                    <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </your_module_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

---

**Clarification:** Magento looks for files with this pattern that either end in ".php" or ".sql", you should only have one of them per upgrade, but not both.

If you want to know how they are executed, see [Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::modifyResourceDb()](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php#L621-L634)

Comment: Is it ".sql" or ".php" ?

Comment: sql. Magento looks for both and treats them accordingly

Comment: Thanks for info. Just for clarification, if ".sql" then only we can use mysql queries syntaxes in it, and if ".php" then both mysql and php, right ?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Thank's ! Working with the SQL file now. Great answer

Comment: data*.sql is not working in magento version 1.9.3.0 as `$regExp     = sprintf('#^%s-(.*)\.php$#i', $actionType);` is available only for .php file in 
function `_getAvailableDataFiles()` in file `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php`.

however sql*.sql is working

Comment: @MineshPatel thanks for the hint, I'll update the answer

Comment: @FabianSchmengler Great :)